# Visual Studio building ASP.NET MVC Web with old dll reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, visual-studio-2013, build

I've been struggling with Visual Studio today but I can't get it working.

The problem is whenever I try to build or rebuild my ASP.NET MVC Web project, then I got the following error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

I found out that problem was caused when the dll file mentioned before is copied to the "Bin" folder as part of the building process. When I checked the details of that file I found out that it was a minor version (4.0.20710.0) compared to the references in my code.

I forgot to mention that this solution is composed by 4 projects: the main project (which is the website) and 3 small projects which are compiled into dlls and added dynamically to the website as areas.

This is what I've checked until now:

***Main project web.config (fragment)***

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

***Main project packages.config (fragment)***

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

***Main project Views web.config (fragment)***

```
  <system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</httpHandlers>

<!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
<pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Also I have checked the same files that I mentioned above in the small projects but no luck until now. The only way to get it working is to run the webpage and manually delete the dll from bin folder and copy the correct version.

I need this to be automatically done by Visual Studio because I have this same problem every time I check out the project in a different computer.

I hope you can help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your references in your projects are the right version, one thing to check is the `Copy Local` property. This is the setting that determines whether the referenced dll is copied to the bin folder.

To check, expand `References` in solution explorer and right-click on the reference `System.Web.Mvc` and click Properties. Make sure `Copy Local` = `True`.